# Does the Canon 50D have a picture style for Lomography?

Tags: canon, style, lo-fi, lomo, effect

Is there a Lomography picture style software for Canon 50D, are there custom camera settings I could use to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: As a general rule, professional cameras don't have cheap gimmicky settings built in, but there'll be plenty of cheap gimmicky software on the net that will do it

Comment: @Dreamager - While I totally agree, Lomo cameras can be pretty cool!

Comment: They can be fun, but they were essentially cheap toy cameras. I'll resist going into a rant about the extortionate prices now it's become 'trendy' ;)

Answer (score 4):

**No built in picture style exists for lomo on the Canon 50D camera.**

Basically you just need to add a vignette, and do a cross processing style that you can achieve in most photo editing software. You also may want to add fake light leaks to get the full effect.

A tutorial for the effect can be found at digital photography school [here](http://www.digital-photography-school.com/how-to-make-digital-photos-look-like-lomo-photography).